# PHP Warning failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, warnings

When i try to access the page  give me a php warning :

```
md5_file(/public_html/: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

But there is a dot after "pages-oubliee" and i don't know where this come from. And how to get rid of this, this dot prevents me from accessing the real directory

Comment: There's probably a redirect being sent by the server. Why don't you just access the "real directory" in the first place?

Comment: Please add all information right into the question, do NOT post images of something.

Comment: That's why i'm trying to do but the "dot" come from no where so i can't @RolandWeber

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems the dot comes from a selectPerso.php file, specifically from this line

`'fileName'=> './flash/personnalisationV2bis.swf',`

Try removing the dot there and see if it helps.

Comment: Sure, no problem :).